# How can I debug a python script from command line using PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, pycharm

I want to debug a `Python` script that takes multiple command line arguments, such as

```
myscript.py --input1 ./dir/file1.txt --input2 ./dir/file2.txt
```

in `Pycharm`. I am aware, that I can use the `Run/Debug Configuration` to add command line arguments. However, I feel that this is rather cumbersome as I have to open a menu every time I want to modify the arguments. Moreover, there is no file name completion when specifying files as arguments.

I would prefer calling `myscript.py` from my favorite shell, where I have file name completion etc., but still, use the `PyCharm` debugger on that script.

Comment: What's your idea about getting argument from your code? I mean trying to get arguments after running the script. Like `raw_input`.

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code using unit tests. Instead of running scripts with arguments you should implement a function `do_awesome_work(input1, input2)` and write test cases with appropriate input. You may then easily run the test cases under PyCharm debugger.

Comment: Is there any reason you're trying to do this? If you're trying to debug with multiple inputs, it may be worth debugging one case and unit testing others. If for some reason you really do need to debug multiple cases, you may want to just bypass the arguments for that debugging, set the values as variables, and test that command line arguments work separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: `Tools> Attach to Process...`

Long anser:

1. Put a following line at very first of your code

   ```
   input("press Enter to continue")
   ```
2. Launch your code in shell

   ```
   myscript.py --input1 ./dir/file1.txt --input2 ./dir/file2.txt
   ```
3. Open Pycharm and use it to open your `myscript.py`. Set `break points` at anywhere you like to debug. Select `Tools> Attach to Process...` and select the process that `myscript.py` is running.
4. Come back to the shell of `myscript.py` and hit `Enter`

Trouble you may get: `ptrace` don't have permission of doing something

Solution:

```
sudo su
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

or you can set 0 directly in

```
/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

Comment: I believe that in the current version it is placed under `Run > Attach to Local Processes...`